# Conditional formatting with dynamic named ranges

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, named-ranges

I'm trying to optimize my conditional formatting in google sheets to improve my overall spreadsheet performance. One thing I've read to improve spreadsheet performance in general, is to use closed ranges (ex $A$3:$A$450) rather than ranges (ex $A:$A) to reduce the number of calculations on empty cells.

I've applied conditional formatting to one sheet based off the ever changing data set of another sheet. Therefore to use an accurate closed range, it would need to be dynamic. I've used Ben Collin's technique for creating [dynamic named ranges](https://www.benlcollins.com/formula-examples/dynamic-named-ranges/) throughout my sheets but it doesn't seem to work for conditional formatting.

The problem is the same function, `indirect("[named_range]")`, does 2 different things depending on where it's used:

- Conditional Formatting requires it to call a regular named range
- When used in a formula in a spreadsheet, it allows you to call dynamic named ranges

So naturally I figured maybe I just need to nest it: `indirect(indirect("[dynamic named range]"))` 
  Unfortunately that doesn't work either. :)

Is there a trick to using dynamic named ranges with conditional formatting? Is it even possible?

Comment: can you share the full formula you're trying to calculate?

Comment: Conditional Formatting should work with named ranges `=match(A1,indirect("I_AM_A_RANGE"),0)`  by using the auxiliary function `indirect`